# iPhone UIWebView Can't connect Some site

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have used `UIWebview` to connect 
[accounts.craigslist.org](https://accounts.craigslist.org/login?lang=en&cc=us)
but it doesn't work.
If i change the site address to google [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
it works.
I am using Proxy but I don't think it's proxy problem.
code below

---

```
self.mWebView.delegate = self;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:15.0];
    [self.mWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

---

Here is [image: pInfo.list screenshot] ( I have seen some solution but doesn't work for me from this site )

And I have applied other solutions with `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` delegate

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSArray *trustedHosts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mytrustedhost",nil];

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host]) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

[Error Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ON4.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the line of code where you are taking the string URL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one

```
NSString *Url=@"accounts.craigslist.org";
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Url];
NSURL *urls=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:str];

[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urls]];
```